# How to use the GitHub actions to add a comment in PR

Tags: curl, yaml, continuous-integration, github-actions, github-api

In GitHub api, there is an [api](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/issues/comments#create-an-issue-comment) to create an issue comment. I want to use it in the GitHub actions CI/CD pipeline.

I create the workflow.

```
name: Workflow

on:
  push:
    branches:
    - main
  pull_request:

jobs:
  test:
    name: Test
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Run jest coverage and log the result to GitHub summary
        run: |
          npm run test-coverage >> $GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY
          echo "UNITTESTCOVERAGE=$GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "" >> $GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY

      - name: Post jest coverage comments
        env:
          PR_NUMBER: ${{ github.event.pull_request.number }}
          REPO: ${{ github.repository }}
          SUMMARY_URL: https://github.com/${{ github.repository }}/actions/runs/${{ github.run_id }}
        run: |
          curl \
            -X POST \
            -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
            -H "Authorization: token ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}" \
            https://api.github.com/repos/$REPO/issues/$PR_NUMBER/comments \
            -d '{"body":"# Job Summary\n'$SUMMARY_URL'\n'$UNITTESTCOVERAGE'\n"}'

  deploy:
    ...
```

Instead of showing the jest coverage result, GitHub bot add the comment.

```
Job Summary
...

/home/runner/work/_temp/_runner_file_commands/step_summary_d0****01-f**9-4**7-b**7-f0******dc3f
```

How to do get the actual result?

---

**Update 1**

I removed unrelated steps to make it clear.

Response

[image: Response from GitHub api]

---

**Update 2**

I set `jest --coverage` to create coverage report in text format (and other formats, not important here), and I want to create a comment to show the text format report.

In `package.json`, I added `npm run test-coverage` to run `Jest` coverage report. Therefore, `npm run test-coverage` will print the result in terminal.

I used `npm run test-coverage >> $GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY` to redirect the result to **GitHub step summary**, so I could see the coverage report in **GitHub step summary**.

I wanted to use GitHub api to create a comment to show the coverage report in the PR. I used `echo "UNITTESTCOVERAGE=$GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY" >> $GITHUB_ENV` to set environment variable `UNITTESTCOVERAGE` to be `$GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY`, and I wished `UNITTESTCOVERAGE` can get the coverage report.

However, the step `Post jest coverage comments` could not get the coverage report. Instead of the report, the comment created by GitHub api showed a file / directory path.

How to add the coverage report to a comment by GitHub api?

Comment: Please show how the last run step is initialised (you should see the values of the variables passed) along with the full logs. Furthermore, please remove the unrelated steps (e.g. lint, step summary).

Comment: You could also try using an action that already calls the API for you ([example](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/add-pr-comment)) from the [Github Marketplace](https://github.com/marketplace?type=actions&query=pr+comment+) that might already treat many different scenarios.

Comment: @rethab I found that I posted old result. I have updated the post, added the screen shot and removed unrelated parts.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and create a minimal reproducing example (this might mean you have to create a new workflow from scratch). Also, please don't paste screenshots, but copy/paste text as that makes it easier to search questions here on SO.

Comment: @rethab I have updated the post and add more explanation. The workflow is the minimal reproducing one, other steps are removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The environment variable `$GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY` is a filename.

What your code does:

- `npm run test-coverage >> $GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY`

  - write the coverage report into the step summary file
- `echo "UNITTESTCOVERAGE=$GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY" >> $GITHUB_ENV`

  - set the environment variable `UNITTESTCOVERAGE` to the same as `GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY` (a filename)
- `echo "" >> $GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY`

  - append empty line to the step summary

What you probably want, however, is to put set the *contents* of the file behind the step summary env variable as the new env variable:

`echo "UNITTESTCOVERAGE=$(cat $GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY)" >> $GITHUB_ENV`